# Should code questions be closed if no code is attempted?

Tags: discussion

Many that know me know I love the code side of design and while I dive deeper in the rabbit hole and attempt to code more in applications like InDesign & Illustrator I frequently am seeing questions like "[Search for string and delete entire text frame with JavaScript](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/102901/search-for-string-and-delete-entire-text-frame-with-javascript)" that I strongly dislike.

While I try to be the first to help with an answer, I'm starting to weigh on wether we should allow a question to stay open anymore because I look at them as spec work and I think for questions like the above linked they should go to the Adobe forums as it's acceptable there.  I think GD.SE's Q&A is better than a continuation of people looking to speed their production but attempt nothing.  Thoughts on this assessment?

What I'm curious to know if others think questions that ask for code and show no code should be closed.

Comment: The Adobe forums have slightly more relaxed rules than GD (and most other SE f̶o̶r̶u̶m̶s̶ sites), but if a poster is asking *too persistent* and/or *too often* for free handouts of fully custom written scripts, s/he will be asked to play fair and show at least some effort by themself, or to post on a paid developers' site.